# How to learn what `gparted`, `partitionmanager`... libcalls or `fdisk`, `parted`... commands are wrapping?

Tags: linux, gparted, fdisk, parted, partitionmanager

Querying `partitionmananger --help` does not document any verbose mode. Even `gparted --help` is not implemented. I wish I could use any `--verbose` mode without more esoteric thingy like using `ltrace`, because unless checking their sources one can not know if they resort only on `libparted` or some operations are performed using system commands, hence not being traced.

I don't know nesting `strace` on `ltrace` or vice-versa... I guess that would be a lot of standard output?

How to learn what `gparted`, `partitionmanager`... libcalls or `fdisk`, `parted`... commands are wrapping? I want to learn to use `parted` and `fdisk` in order not to need to rely on GUI interfaces such as `gparted` or `partitionmanager`, as I currently more or less know how to use the `lvm` suite of operations but not the *more arcane* `fdisk` and `parted`, but I guess it should help a lot watching actual examples of `parted`, `fdisk` and libparted being invoked by the user use of, for instance, `gparted`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly (and I might not), then I think that you wish to determine which libraries are being used by a particular application.  In this case `ldd` is your friend.

`ldd /path/to/binary`

`gparted` is actually a script (well it is on my Debian Wheezy box), and to determine the executables which are being called, simply `cat /usr/sbin/gparted` and read the script. When you find the exectuable files you are interested in, you can run ldd to determine which libraries are being linked to.

If you want a more verbose answer for a particular application, you can always download the source code if the software is open source, and have a look there. Usually you will find a file called `INSTALL` ( you can get from package developer's website or in most GNU/Linux distributions you may find it also in `/usr/share/doc/`) which tell you which libraries the software depends on before you can compile it.

Comment: I actually know `gparted` requires and uses `libparted`, `ldd` is not completely necessary for knowing this because it is stated by the description of the gparted package and because the package depends on libparted (libparted0debian1 actually for Debian 7 _wheezy_). I edited the question to state more precisely I want to see actual calls to the functions of the library, not just know which library it depends on. I just thought I'ld break less partitions if I use the `parted` documentation not only by itself but together actual libparted examples coming from a `gparted` verbose mode.

Comment: I think that the only solution to this would be to examine the source code of the package. However, I found this, which might be useful? [libparted_handbook.pdf](http://zester.googlecode.com/files/libparted_handbook.pdf)